# Cannot Delete Files in user file handler open in directory?

Tags: ssh, files, stream

If I have an open SSH session in a server, and I am browsing a particular directory, and another user tries to delete the directory I am in, does the delete folder fail?

I am assuming yes, but the files inside the directory get deleted. I think I am also confusing file handle with something else, but any advisory is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'browsing'? I have opened 2 terminals. In one I did `cd a`, in the second I did `rm -r a`: no problem, a was removed.

Answer (score 0):

> does the delete folder fail

No. Deleting is the removal of the link from the directory above + removal of the link to ".." and to ".". The directory itself remains if there are process active, or it is a current working directory.

Whenever you try to do something in that directory you will get an error notice. `ls`, `rm`, `cd` will all fail if done to something inside that, now deleted, location.